# Coupled elliptic pdes, FEM solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I have been working on $$\mathcal{L} \psi =f$$ $$\mathcal{L} f =0$$
$$\frac{\partial{\psi(r,\theta)}}{\partial r}|_{r=1}=0$$ $$\frac{\partial{\psi(r,\theta)}}{\partial r}|_{r=3}=-\frac{20(\sin[\theta])^{2}}{9}=\mu(\theta)$$ $$\psi(r=1,\theta)=0$$ 
$$\psi(r=3,\theta)=\frac{7}{3}(\sin(\theta))^{2}$$ where  $$\mathcal{L}u=\triangledown.(\triangledown u)-\frac{2\cot(\theta)}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} -\frac{2}{r}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}}$$ such that u is a scalar function given in spherical coordinates.
We need to put this set of pde in flux form to figure out the NeumanValues: then you obtain:
$$\mathcal{L}\psi=\triangledown.(-c\triangledown\psi -\alpha\triangledown\psi)$$
You find out $$c=-1,$$ $$\alpha =\big(\frac{2}{r},\frac{2\cot(\theta)}{r},0\big)$$ Therefore $$\vec{n} .(c.\triangledown \psi +\alpha \psi)=-\psi_{r}(r,\theta)+\frac{2}{r}\psi(r,\theta)$$
We also have the following exact solution: $$\psi(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{4}(2r^{2}-3r+\frac{1}{r})\sin{(\theta)^{2}}.$$ I have the following mathematica script :

```
    c = 1;
    d = 3;

    eqn11 = D[D[ps[r, t], r], r] + 
     Sin[t]/r^2*
    D[1/Sin[t]*D[ps[r, t], t], t];

    eqn21 = D[D[w[r, t], r], r] + 
    Sin[t]/r^2*
    D[1/Sin[t]*D[w[r, t],t], t];
    W = Rectangle[{c, 0}, {d, Pi}];    
    astream[r_, t_] := 1/4*(2*r^2 - 3*r + 1/r)*(Sin[t])^2;
    N1 = 
    NeumannValue[(-(1/4) (-3 - 1/r^2 + 4 r) *(Sin[t])^2 + 
    2/r*(astream[r, t])), r == 1];
    N2 = 
    NeumannValue[(-(1/4) (-3 - 1/r^2 + 4 r) *(Sin[t])^2 + 
    2/r*(astream[r, t])), r == d];
    bcs = {DirichletCondition[ps[r, t] == astream[r, t],
    r == 1 || r == d]};
    ui = NDSolveValue[
    {eqn11 == w[r,t] +N1 + 
    N2, eqn21 == 0, bcs},
   {ps, w}, Element[{r,t}, W], 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0005}, 
    "IntegrationOrder" -> 5}}
     ]
```

To visualize the output:

```
   streamfunction = 
   TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   ui[[1]][r, t], {r, t} -> {x, z}];
   ContourPlot[streamfunction, {x, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 50, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

Here is the exact solution in cartesian coordinates:

```
   ContourPlot[(
   z^2 (1 - 3 x^2 - 3 z^2 + 2 x^2 Sqrt[x^2 + z^2] + 
   2 z^2 Sqrt[x^2 + z^2]))/(
   4 (x^2 + z^2)^(3/2)), {x, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Temperature", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   Contours -> 50, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, z}, 1 < x^2 + z^2 < 3^2], 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

If  you compare the exact solution with the numerical solution for a specific value of $\theta$ you have :

```
  Plot[(1/4*(2*r^2 - 3*r + 1/r)*(Sin[t])^2 /. {r -> 
  q, t -> Pi/4}) - (ui[[1]][
  r, t] /. {r -> q, t-> Pi/4}), {q, 1, 3}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

I could not get a convergent numerical solution to the exact solution. I was wondering what is that I am doing wrong. What also came to my attention is that the first Neumann boundary condition is not really effecting the output at all. I just did not understand. I would be so happy to know the reason of this awkward behavior of the solution.

Comment: Using `Subscript` just invites problems.  I recommend against it.  `Also, `Subscript[\[CapitalGamma], N^1]` seems strange.

Comment: @bbgodfrey do you have any other comments to make it work , I already fixed what you have found problematic? thanks

Comment: Whether or not the issue you have identified is a bug, I think that it should be reported to Wolfram, Inc.  Do you wish to do so, or should I?

Comment: @bbgodfrey thanks so much for taking time to show me even a simpler case where things do not work out. do you mind if I let them know about this or we both can let them know I guess:).  I will also try the flux form through the original operators before we ask them what is wrong with this in case they will tell us that the operators also have to be in their original form if we want to make use of finite element method for pde's. However it seems like there is definitely something not working even in that coupled ode case.

Comment: Please do report this problem to Wolfram, Inc.  I hope you will become a regular contributor to StackExchange.  When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge; remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t); and give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a partial solution; especially to the issues of @bbgodfrey 's answer. Let's look at the fourth-order ODE:

```
s1 = Flatten@
   NDSolveValue[{ps''''[x] == 0, ps[0] == 0, ps'[0] == 0, ps[1] == 1, 
     ps'[1] == 1}, {ps[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[s1, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

This fourth-order ODE can be re-written as a system of two coupled second-order ODEs.

```
s2 = Flatten@
   NDSolveValue[{ps''[x] == w[x], w''[x] == 0, ps[0] == 0, 
     ps'[0] == 0, ps[1] == 1, ps'[1] == 1}, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 
     1}];
Plot[s2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[s1[[1]] - s2[[1]], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Now, bbgodfrey proposed the following:

```
N1 = NeumannValue[0, x == 0]; N2 = NeumannValue[1, x == 1];
s3 = Flatten@
   NDSolveValue[{ps''[x] == w[x] + N1 + N2, w''[x] == 0, 
     DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 0, x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 1, x == 1]}, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 
     1}];
Plot[s3, {x, 0, 1}]
```

This works as it should but does not give the intended solution. What happens is that at the end points we have multiple boundary conditions, one `DirichletCondition` and a `NeumannValue` at each end. One thing to remember with the Finite Element Method is that `NeumannValue` is not really equal to the Derivative of a function. The `NeumannValue` is satisfied in a weak sense (see the section [The Relation between NeumannValue and Boundary Derivatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html)). When you have a `DirichletCondition` and a `NeumannValue` at a boundary then the `DirichletCondition` will overwrite the `NeumannValue`.

How can we word around that? Two ways. One is if you have additional information you may be able to specify an additional `DirichletCondition` on the auxiliary equation like so:

```
s4 = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{ps''[x] == w[x],
     w''[x] == 0,
     DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 0, x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 1, x == 1],
     DirichletCondition[w[x] == 4, x == 0], 
     DirichletCondition[w[x] == -2, x == 1]
     }, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[s4, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[s2 - s4, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Note that this also got rid of the warning that the solution is not unique.

Another way to do it is the following trick to decouple the overlapping boundary conditions:

```
s5 = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{
     ps''[x] == 
      w[x] - NeumannValue[0, x == 0] - NeumannValue[1, x == 1],
     w''[x] == 
      DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 0, x == 0] + 
       DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 1, x == 1]
     }, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "FiniteElement"];
Plot[s5, {x, 0, 1}]

NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {ps}; the result may not be unique.
```

[image]

```
Plot[s1[[1]] - s5[[1]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

OK, what is this doing? One can associate `DirichletConditions` to a specific equation in exactly the same way as `NeumannValues` are. The reason that this functionality is undocumented is that I never had an application for it - now it seems we have that. This works by applying the `NeumannValue` and the `DirichletCondition` at different positions in the global stiffness matrix. If you like to know more about that, let me know and I'll extend the post.

Regarding the warning message: In some cases not specifying a `DirichletConditon` or a Robin-type `NeumannValue` on some of the equations will deliver a solution with is correct but only up to a constant value - it's a bit like an integration constant. I am not aware of any analysis where I can tell reliably that this such and such a case this is or is not going to happen, that's why the warning is there. In this case it's benign I think. In a future version I have reworded the warning message a bit and it will read:

```
NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {ps}; the result may not be unique.
```

This, I think, makes it clearer that this a warning and things *may* go south but don't have to.

Very unfortunately, when using this technique on the original problem it does not quite work:

```
c = 1;
d = 3;
eqn11 = D[D[ps[r, t], r], r] + 
   Sin[t]/r^2*D[1/Sin[t]*D[ps[r, t], t], t];
eqn21 = D[D[w[r, t], r], r] + 
   Sin[t]/r^2*D[1/Sin[t]*D[w[r, t], t], t];
W = Rectangle[{c, 0}, {d, Pi}];
astream[r_, t_] := 1/4*(2*r^2 - 3*r + 1/r)*(Sin[t])^2;
N2 = NeumannValue[(-(1/4) (-3 - 1/r^2 + 4 r)*(Sin[t])^2 + 
     2/r*(astream[r, t])), r == 1 || r == d];
ui = NDSolveValue[{eqn11 == w[r, t] + N2, 
   eqn21 == 
    DirichletCondition[ps[r, t] == astream[r, t], 
     r == 1 || r == d]}, {ps, w}, Element[{r, t}, W]]

opts = {ColorFunction -> "Temperature", Contours -> 50, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic};
streamfunction = 
  TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   ui[[1]][r, t], {r, t} -> {x, z}];
anasol = TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   astream[r, t], {r, t} -> {x, z}];
(*ContourPlot[streamfunction,{x,-3,3},{z,0,3},Evaluate[opts]]*)
Plot3D[streamfunction - anasol, {x, -3, 3}, {z, 0, 3}, Evaluate[opts]]
```

[image]

It seems the boundary conditions are OK, but some energy is generated in the region. I don't know the reason for that; I have trouble following the derivation in the question and see how it relates the the implementation. There might be an issue here. An alternative thing to check is if this cases needs `Inactive` equations - discussed in the [NeumannValue and Formal Partial Differential Equations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) section.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following 1D analogue of the PDE in the question:

```
N1 = NeumannValue[0, x == 0]; N2 = NeumannValue[1, x == 1];
s3 = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{ps''[x] == w[x] + N1 + N2, w''[x] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 0, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 1, x == 1]}, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
```

> NDSolveValue::femibcnd: No DirichletCondition or Robin-type NeumannValue was specified for {w}; the result is not unique up to a constant.

which is the same error message received when running the code in the question.  The solution obtained is,

```
Plot[s3, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

This problem can be solved without `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue` as follows.

```
s2 = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{ps''[x] == w[x], w''[x] == 0, ps[0] == 0, ps'[0] == 0,
    ps[1] == 1, ps'[1] == 1}, {ps[x], w[x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[s2, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

It yields the correct answer, and no error message.

**Edit: paragraph added.**  Evidently, `NDSolveValue` becomes confused by this particular fourth-order ODE system, in which all boundary conditions are applied to one of the two ODEs, but only when using `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue`.  According to the documentation for `NeumannValue`, when no boundary condition is provided for part of the boundary of a differential equation, a homogeneous Neumann boundary condition is assumed. Since the ODE for `w[x]` has no associated boundary conditions in the `s3` computation, `NDSolveValue` may make that assumption.  Then, with a homogeneous ODE and homogeneous boundary conditions, the solution obviously is a constant, taken by `NDSolveValue` to be `0`.  This line of thought would explain both the error message and the `w[x] == 0` solution obtained in the `s3` computation.  Then, when `NDSolveValue` turns to the `ps[x]` ODE, it encounters too many boundary conditions.  It appears simply to ignore two of them, namely `N2` and `DirichletCondition[ps[x] == 1, x == 1]`.  Admittedly, this final paragraph is but a plausibility argument, but it seems reasonable.

In any case, I believe that the same thing is happening with the fourth-order PDE system in the question, especially because plotting `w[r,t]` from the code in the question shows it to be of order `10^-8`.

**Addendum: Attempted 2D Work-Arounds**

Not using `DirichletCondition` and `NeumannValue` for the 1D example presented above led to the correct answer.  Unfortunately, trying to do the same in 2D is unsuccessful.

```
bcs = {ps[1, t] == astream[1, t], ps[d, t] == astream[d, t], 
    (D[ps[r, t], r] /. r -> 1) == 0, (D[ps[r, t], r] /. r -> d) == -2 Sin[t]^2/3};
ui = NDSolveValue[{eqn11 == w[r, t] , eqn21 == 0, bcs}, {ps, w}, {r, 1, d}, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

returns unevaluated with the error message,

> NDSolveValue::fembdnl: The dependent variable in (ps^(1,0))[1,t]==0 in the boundary condition DirichletCondition[(ps^(1,0))[1,t]==0,r==1.] needs to be linear.

(This error message makes no sense, again suggesting that `NDSolveValue` is confused by the PDE system.)  Combining the two second order PDEs into one fourth-order PDE also fails.

```
eqn = D[D[(D[D[ps[r, t], r], r] + Sin[t]/r^2*D[1/Sin[t]*D[ps[r, t], t], t]), r], r] + 
    Sin[t]/r^2*D[1/Sin[t]*D[(D[D[ps[r, t], r], r] + 
    Sin[t]/r^2*D[1/Sin[t]*D[ps[r, t], t], t]), t], t];
ui = NDSolveValue[{eqn == 0, bcs}, {ps}, {r, 1, d}, {t, 0, Pi}]]
```

> NDSolveValue::femcmsd: The spatial derivative order of the PDE may not exceed two.

It may be that `NDSolve` and its variants simply are unable to solve the PDE system in the question.

**I would welcome comments on whether the situation described here is a bug.**

Comment: Please see my answer to your questions. Let me know what you think.

Comment: @user21  Very useful(+1).  However, I do believe that the documentation should be improved.  Your sentence, "One thing to remember with the Finite Element Method is that NeumannValue is not really equal to the Derivative of a function." makes a very important point and should be put in the main `NeumannValue` documentation.  Many users do not visit the lengthy supplementary documentation often.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about that. Thanks.

Comment: @user21  Any new insights on this question?  Thanks.

Comment: I have been on vacation so I only get back to you now. In V12.2 there is a new 'details' note: [NeumannValue #1519527780](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html#1519527780). The >> take you to the place where this is explained in detail. Let me know if you think this suffices.

Comment: @user21  This is very helpful.  Thanks.